# AWS EC2 Nginx available at every port only not 80

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, amazon-web-services, http, port

Currently, I'm new to Nginx and hope that you can guide me to the right direction.

I've tried to follow nearly every guide I found online, including uninstalling and reinstalling each time configs using this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12363195/3673659

Moreover, I relaunched a new instance and only installed nginx. Here port 80 works from beginning using the same security group as with the one not working.

The one which doesnt work has been modified with ubuntu-gui, vnc4server, nodejs and npm and mongoose.

a netstat -nlt returns:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::5901                 :::*                    LISTEN
ubuntu@ip-172-31-47-254:~$
```

running nginx -t returns:

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

my /conf.d/ folder is empty
my /sites-available/ folder has a default file with following settings
[image]

my /sites-enabled/ folder has a default file with following settings
[image]

What I can conclude until now is:
- it has nothing to do with the security group
- it should have happend because of the ubuntu-gui as comparing netstat -nlt from the working and non working one, the non working one is missing

```
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

...and this took me now about 5h to find this much out.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: A couple of suggestions 1) Please edit your question to show the config in text, rather than a screenshot 2) Please precisely and clearly define the problem you're having and desired state at the top of the question. Also, you almost never need to uninstall and reinstall Nginx, you just change the config then restart the service.

Comment: What I conclude is that nginx hasn't been started.

Comment: @Tim, what you can see on the screenshot are the only "non #" lines. And I want to access the AWS from an external pc with only using the IP.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Nginx is available, on the machine, with localhost and 127.0.0.1

Comment: It may be available, but it isn't running.

Comment: It's general good practice and it's polite to put config in as text so that if anyone wants to edit a small portion to help you they don't have to type it out. As a new contributor we give you guidance as to how things are best done on SF. Expanding your question means you'll get more help, right now it's not easy to understand so you'll get less help.

Comment: @Gerhard, it is accessible when I type in the Ubuntu GUI on firefox localhost

Comment: You said it wasn't working, you showed a netstat where no process was listening on port 80. Is firefox showing something from his cache?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille nope, even in icognito mode and with developer tools opened and disabled cache, it still works on localhost

Comment: Try http: / /ip-172-31-47-254/ or http: / /172.31.47.254/ (without spaces between //)